# Fdisk creates 1K extended partition instead of the mentioned size

Tags: linux, arch-linux, partition, fdisk

Trying to install arch on my dell using fdisk and MBR (DOS "o")

I created 3 partitions:

- sda1 root
- sda2 swap
- sda3 extended

But `lsblk` says `sda3` is 1KiB even though I specifically selected "+69G" which is the remaining space of my disk. I can even confirm this my typing "p" to print partition table which says 69 GB extended volume.

So far I have tried changing the `sda3` type to `lvm` and writing the changes but i faced the same result with `lsblk` showing it as 1KiB.

When I use `pvcreate` it says device too small.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Extended partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_boot_record) provides space for logical partitions, if you want to use the free space for LVM physical volume, you must add a new logical partition for it, extended partition itself is just a "container" and can't be formatted. That's also why `lsblk` shows it as being 1 KiB, because it is in fact only 2 sectors big (2 * 512 B) -- it only holds metadata (positions of the logical partitions, it really is a second partition table, a hack used to overcome the 4 primary partition limit in the MSDOS partition table) and `lsblk` doesn't show the free space "inside" the extended partition.

So to use the space, use `fdisk /dev/sda` to a new logical partition (same way you added the primary and extended partitions, just the type will be "logical"), it will be added "inside" the extended partition and then use `pvcreate` to create LVM PV on it: `# pvcreate /dev/sda5` (first logical partition will always be `sda5` (on `sda`)).

Comment: Like you said I went inside the sda3 partition with fdisk and created new primary partition but type "logical"  was not on the list so I selected type "Linux LVM" and `pvcreate /dev/sda5` was not picking it up either. Says no device found. `lsblk` doesn't show sda5 either.

Comment: Run `fdisk /dev/sda`, add new partition using `n`, if it asks for partition type, select `l` for *logical*. It's possible it won't asks if you don't have enough free space for a third primary partition, in this case `fdisk` will create logical partition without asking .

Comment: Yes that worked. I didn't check going back to `Fdisk dev/sda` after I created the lvm in sda3. Oddly enough there aren't many tutorials out there going over making lvm for dos. Thank you :)